# Some bug in html,css file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just learned some HTML and css so I tried to make a simple website with it
using this code
why "problem solving" is pink, not blue?
it's not a real problem but I really didn't know how to solve it

[image: image1]

this is the website i've made

```
<style>
*{
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;

}
body{
    background-color: #17202A ;
}
    h1{
        color: #AB2C5C;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    h2{
        font-size: 26px;
    }
    h3{
        font-size: 23px;
    }
.x{
  color: #4D5656 !important;
  
}
.ol1{
  border:  1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  font-size: 18px;

}
.ul1{
    border:  1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
.ol2{
    border:  1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
.ul2{
        border:  1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
#p1{
    width: 150;
    height:auto;
    border: 3px solid;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#p1:hover{
    Color: darkred;
}
#p2:hover{
    Color: darkred;
}
#p2{
    border: 3px solid;
    height:auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    width:auto;
    margin: 4px;
}

</style>
```

and this is the css on it so what is the proplem ?

Comment: Please share your HTML code So we can review better it Or please let me knowwhich tag or class you have added "problem-solving" this text?

Comment: 'proplem solving' is in shade of blue, not pink. it is because you have already click on that anchor tag once, now its showing as visited.

Comment: stackoverflow says its alot of code i will try to post it in github so u can see

Comment: @TarekHassan Use Codepen, add your code, save and and share the link :)

Comment: yeah thanks here is the full code : https://codepen.io/12Tarek1hassan12/pen/JjrdmMw

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that all HTML links have 4 states.

**link** , **visited** , **active** and **hover**.

And for each of these states it takes a particular color in HTML by default. By default in normal state it appears blue.

If you want to override any of these you can use the CSS for that:
eg,

```
a:visited {
  color:orange; /*or which ever color you need*/
}

a:hover {
  color: red; /*your CSS value*/
}
```

Similarly for other two.

Comment: Not my friend, I'm sorry but all CSS style sheets are **case-insensitive**.

Comment: Dear Friend, @OlavoMello All CSS style sheets are `case-insensitive`. What is your confusion dear?

Comment: https://codepen.io/12Tarek1hassan12/pen/WNZvaJj even without CSS its pink how is this even possible?

Comment: Let me check :)

Comment: In your answer you said "Note that CSS properties are case-sensitive. You have used Color, it should be color and also do check whether darkred is any color or not." 
But it is not right. OR I lose something ? :/

Comment: Perhaps you are right @OlavoMello Not all CSS properties are `case-sensitive`. Thank you so much. Only there are exceptions where CSS properties are case `case-insensitive`. I thank you a lot :)

Comment: No problem my friend. We are all together and learning always :)

Comment: Ya, I actually quickly checked OPs CSS earlier and thought that `Color` may be the issue. 
But Now, I read the question again and have updated my answer accordingly :) 

Stay Blessed. 
Cheers !!!

Comment: Stay Blessed you too Imran. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that  tag, used in links, when visited, by default is changed to pink.

In CSS when you use this to change a LINK in your comum state.

```
a { 
    color : blue;
}
```

Using this way, you will change HOVER state :

```
a:hover { 
    color : red;
}
```

This way, you will change VISITED state :

```
a:visited { 
    color : orange;
}
```

And This way, you will change ACTIVE state :

```
a:active { 
    color : pink;
}
```

Each CSS will apply CSS relative to the state of the link.

Try this to solve :

```css
             *{
                  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
                  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
                  font-size: 20px;
                  width: auto;
                  height: auto;
                  text-align: center;
                  font-family: sans-serif;

              }
              body{
                  background-color:#17202A;
              }
                  h1{
                      color:#AB2C5C;
                      font-size: 30px;
                  }
                  h2{
                      font-size: 26px;
                  }
                  h3{
                      font-size: 23px;
                  }
              .x{
                color: #4D5656 !important;
                
              }
              .ol1{
                border:  1px 1px 1px 1px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
                font-size: 18px;

              }
              .ul1{
                  border:  1px 1px 1px 1px;
                border-style: solid;
                font-size: 18px;
                border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
              }
              .ol2{
                  border:  1px 1px 1px 1px;
                border-style: solid;
                font-size: 18px;
                border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
              }
              .ul2{
                      border:  1px 1px 1px 1px;
                border-style: solid;
                font-size: 18px;
                border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
              }
              #p1{
                  width: 150;
                  height:auto;
                  border: 3px solid;
                  font-size: 18px;
                  margin: 10px;
              }
              #p1:hover{
                  Color: darkred;
              }
              #p2:hover{
                  Color: darkred;
              }
              #p2{
                  border: 3px solid;
                  height:auto;
                  font-size: 18px;
                  width:auto;
                  margin: 4px;
              }

              /* This is the key */
              a, a:hover, a:visited, a:active{
                color:#0000ff;
              }
```

```html
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Only a test</title>
          </head>
          <body>
            <h1>Hello there!</h1>
            <h2>Hello there!</h2>
            <h2 class="x">Hello there!</h2>
            <h3>Hello there!</h3>
            <h4>Hello there!</h4>
            <ul id="ul1"><li>Test</li></ul>
            <ol id="ol1"><li>Test</li></ol>
            <ul id="ul2"><li>Test</li></ul>
            <ol id="ol2"><li>Test</li></ol> 
            <p id="p1">Test</p>   
            <p id="p2">Test</p>  
            <a href="#">Your link</a> 
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: actully thanks but can u explain why does this solve the proplem ?

Comment: Sure. I´ll add in the answer to help others too ok

Comment: Done my friend. Mark as solved to help other ;)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


    <div class = "xd"><h1>Things you must learn to be good at programming:</h1>
        <ol class="ol1">
                <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_solving">Proplem Solving</li></a>
            
            <p id ="p1">Problem solving consists of using generic or ad hoc methods in an orderly manner to find solutions to difficulties.</p>
                <li style = "font-size:25px"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_reasoning">Logical Thinking     </li></a>
            <p id ="p2">Logical thinking is the act of analyzing a situation and coming up with a sensible solution. Similar to critical thinking, logical thinking requires the use of reasoning skills to study a problem objectively, which will allow you to make a rational conclusion about how to proceed.</p>
                <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics">Mathematics</li></a><p>Mathematics (from Greek: μάθημα, máthēma, 'knowledge, study, learning') includes the study of such topics as numbers (arithmetic and number theory), formulas and related structures (algebra), shapes and spaces in which they are contained (geometry), and quantities and their changes (calculus and analysis). There is no general consensus about its exact scope or epistemological status.</p>
        </ol>   
        <ul class="ul1"><h2>Things you must learn to be a good front-end developer:</h2>
            <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS">CSS</li></a>
            <p>Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is a style sheet language used for describing the presentation of a document written in a markup language such as HTML.CSS is a cornerstone technology of the World Wide Web, alongside HTML and JavaScript.</p>
            <li>JavaScript</li>
            <li>ReactFramework</li>
        </ul>
        <ol class="ol2"><h3>Things you must learn to be good at CSS:</h3>
            <li>CSS specifity</li>
            <li>Floats</li>
            <li>Positioning</li>
            <li>Display</li>
            <li>Box Model</li>
            <li>CSS Grid</li>
            <li>Flex Box</li>
            <li>Media Queries</li>
        </ol>
        <ul class="ul2"><h4>Things you must learn to be good at JavaScript:</h4>
            <li>Basic Syntax</li>
            <li>OOP</li>
            <li>Dom manupilation</li>
            <li>Ajax/Fetch Api/Promises</li>
            <li>Asynchronous JS(Async/Await)</li>
            <li>Scoping/Hoisting/Closures</li>
            <li>Refrence/Value</li>
            <li>JSON</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</body>
<style>
*{
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;

}
body{
    background-color: #17202A ;
}
    h1{
        color: #AB2C5C;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    h2{
        font-size: 26px;
    }
    h3{
        font-size: 23px;
    }
.xd{
  color: #4D5656 !important;
  
}
.ol1{
  border:  1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  font-size: 18px;

}
.ul1{
    border:  1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
.ol2{
    border:  1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
.ul2{
        border:  1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
#p1{
    width: 150;
    height:auto;
    border: 3px solid;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#p1:hover{
    Color: darkred;
}
#p2:hover{
    Color: darkred;
}
#p2{
    border: 3px solid;
    height:auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    width:auto;
    margin: 4px;
}
a:visited {
  color: blue;
}

</style>

</html>
```

Comment: you have visited that links that's why it shows pink but if you want to blue color of your visited link then add the code which I have added .